# Excel: Two way relation: value of Field 1 after inserting Field 2 into Field 3

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet where I do some multi-line calculations, based on a value in a certain field, returning a final result. This certain field can take a list of values, and I need the result for each one. Is there a better way than inserting and copying manually for every single one? THanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of values and their corresponding results, you can use the `VLOOKUP` function.  Say your list of values is in cells `A1:A10`, making your corresponding results in cells `B1:B10`, and that your certain value is in cell C1.  You can use `VLOOKUP` like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1, A1:B10, 1, FALSE)
```

This will look up `C1`'s value in the table `A1:B10` and return its corresponding value.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is how to get the corresponding results without copying and inserting manually (the calculation has many steps and is more than one line)

Comment: Well in that case, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: Say I have a formula that I want to apply to a list of values. As long as the formula fits into a single field, there is no problem. I just copy it down, using relative markers.
But my formula is complicated, and needs a whole sheet to implement. What can I do now?

Comment: "needs a whole sheet to implement."  What does that mean?

Comment: well of course not literally a whole sheet but at least several lines. It uses some ideas that would be very counter-intuitive to put in one line, partly because, based on the one value, it uses a lot of data from another sheet.

Comment: You're gonna have to explain what exactly you're trying to do.  Sorry, but I'm not really getting it.

Comment: OK I have a list of health insurance options. For each one I need to calculate the needed reserve for ibnr claims. So I take the name of the option, look up some data for that option from another sheet, do some calculations and come up with an ibnr reserve. If I put another option's name into the sheet it will give me the ibnr reserve for that option. I need the ibnr reserve for every single option reported in the file, but dont want to copy down the whole calculation process for every option.

Comment: How do you expect it to calculate something if you don't drag a formula down?  Unless you want this done with VBA?

Comment: I don't know, that's the question. And I can't just drag it down, because it is multiple rows. And copying it over and over is like duplicating code... Probably needs VBA